# Params missing on Rails testing with Rspec and Capybara

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, rspec

I'm working on a Rails application and implementing the testing phase using Rspec and capybara. Here's the scenario:

```
 scenario 'A valid user uploads a valid note' do
    tag
    topic
    faculty
    user 
    user.confirm
    visit signin_path
    fill_in 'Email', with: user.email
    fill_in 'Password', with: 'password'
    click_button 'Log in'
    expect(page.find('#messaggio_login')).to have_text('Welcome')
    visit new_note_path


    find("#note_name").set('note test')

    expect(find('#note_name').value).to eq "note test"

    find("#note_description").set('note test')


    attach_file('file', Rails.root + 'spec/support/files/test_file.docx')

    expect(find('#tag'+tag.id.to_s)).not_to be_checked
    find('input', id: 'tag'+tag.id.to_s).click
    expect(find("#tag"+tag.id.to_s)).to be_checked

    expect(find('#topic'+topic.id.to_s)).not_to be_checked
    find('input', id: 'topic'+topic.id.to_s).click
    expect(find("#topic"+topic.id.to_s)).to be_checked
    
    expect(page).to have_select('note_faculty_id')
    select('Ingegneria Informatica', from: 'note_faculty_id')
    expect(page).to have_select('note_faculty_id', selected: 'Ingegneria Informatica')
    
    click_button 'Carica'
    expect(current_path).to eq "/notes/1"
  end
```

This scenario tests the functionality of uploading notes to the site using a form that includes fields for name, description, file, tags, topics, and faculty.

Here are the parameters passed to the controller during the test with RSpec:

```
{
  "file": #<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile: ...>,
  "note": {
    "tag_ids": ["1"],
    "topic_ids": ["1"],
    "faculty_id": "1"
  },
  "commit": "Carica",
  "controller": "notes",
  "action": "create"
}
```

And here are the parameters when manually creating a note:

```
{
  "authenticity_token": "...",
  "note": {
    "name": "nome prova",
    "description": "descrizione prova",
    "tag_ids": ["2"],
    "topic_ids": ["4"],
    "faculty_id": "7"
  },
  "file": #<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile: ...>,
  "commit": "Carica",
  "controller": "notes",
  "action": "create"
}
```

As you can see, during the test phase, the parameters for "name" and "description" are not being sent. This prevent the test to success.

I tried to verify if the 'Name' and 'Description' fields of my form were actually being filled using fill_in, and I observed that they do get filled. I'm unsure how to resolve this issue.

Comment: From your browser, copy/paste the HTML form from your new note page into your question.